# AWS SNS SMS getting delivered but response of publish function giving 500 internal error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

**Here is my code**

```
$sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => 'my_key',
                'secret' => 'my_secret'
            ),
            'region' => 'us-west-2',
            'version' => 'latest'
        ));

$msgattributes = [
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => 'Klassroom',
    ],
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
    ]
];

$payload = array(
    'Message' => 'this is mine cre',
    'PhoneNumber' => '+91**********',
    'MessageAttributes' => $msgattributes
);

$result=$sns->publish($payload)->get('MessageId');
```

Using above code when I run this code I am getting messages to my mobile but I am not getting any response (it is saying 500 internal error). Can any one help me in this please.
My `AWS SDK version is 3.33`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, problem with SimpleXMLElement. i have installed xml for php 7.o by following command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

And then restart apache or nginx server and it is working fine.